# non noetherian rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, noetherian

There are many questions about Examples of a non-Noetherian rings on this site, but this is a bit different.

Let $f:R\to S$ be a homomorphism and R be Noetherian. If $f$ is surjective, then $S$ is also
Noetherian. But there are examples (on the site) that $f$ is 1-1, while $S$ is non-Noetherian.

What if $f$ is not surjective and not 1-1? is there *examples* that $S$ is *non-Noetherian*?

Thank you.

Comment: You are relaxing the conditions on $f$ that force $S$ to be Noetherian. It makes it easier. For example, take a non-trivial quotient $R\to R/I$ and define $S=R/I[x_1,x_2,x_3,...]$ and $f:R\to S$ to be the same quotient function. If you want $S$ local, make it local  localizing at $(x_1,x_2,...)$.

Comment: Thank you very much plop

Comment: similar to the example of @plop, let $g:R\to S$ be any map from a Noetherian ring $R$ to a non-Noetherian ring $S$. now define $f:R[x]\to S$ by extending $f(x)=0$ and $f(r)=g(r)$ for all $r\in R$. $R[x]$ is still Noetherian by [Hilbert's basis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_basis_theorem), so this gives an example

Comment: thank you very much. good help.